# Transfer fund from stripe platform account to a recipient by email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

One of my clients have a situation to pay their website user directly from platform account to user. I can do it by using their transfer payment API.

But, my client want to pay to user's email so that user can have option to perform rest of the action.

I went through their API documentation but don't see anything related to do that. Does anyone have similar experience or know anything related to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's API doesn't have anything like that, but it is something you may be able to build into your application.

I think you might want to contact [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/email) and fill them in on your use case and see if they can offer you some specific suggestions.